# Why was it called “arithmetization” of analysis?

Tags: soft-question, math-history

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetization_of_analysis#History)

> Kronecker originally introduced the term *arithmetization of analysis*, by which he meant its constructivization in the context of the natural numbers …

Why did he call this construction (apparently of real numbers) from natural numbers *arithmetization*?
Is it because every real number is a limit of some convergent series (obtained by addition operator of arithmetic) of rationals (obtained by the division operation of arithmetic applied on naturals)? But did he *know* that?

Comment: There were some language shifts from Kronecker to the beginning of the 20th century and from there to today. So it might be misleading to ask for motivation from today's interpretation of the sentence, you need to translate the mathematical terms to their modern equivalents first.

Comment: Because the "project" was aimed at founding analysis on the theory of real numbers (number=arithmetic) instead that founding it on geometrical intuition.